# LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates not responding

Tags: android, listener, android-location

I am trying to make an app where an intent service is running in the background and getting the location of the user by the network provider, and when the user is close to his destination(a phone-call gate) its starts another IntentService for the specific gate and get location updates more often by the gps provider.
Problem is when I try to get the location on the more active intentservice it doesn't respond at all.

here is the code in my onStartCommand:

```
Bundle gateData = intent.getExtras();
    gateLat = gateData.getDouble("latitude");
    gateLong = gateData.getDouble("longitude");
    gateName = gateData.getString("gateName");
    gatePhoneNumber = gateData.getString("gatePhoneNumber");
    gateId = gateData.getInt("gateId");
    Log.i("Active onStartCommand for:", gateId+"\n"+gateName+"\n phone:"+gatePhoneNumber);
    helper = new MyGatesOpenHelper(this);
    currentGate = helper.getGate(gateId);
    currentGate.setMode(Gate.MODE_ONHOLD);
    helper.updateGate(currentGate);
    results = new float[3];
    aManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    aListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            Log.i("onLocationChanged coords","Lat:"+location.getLatitude()+" Long:"+location.getLongitude());

        }
    };
    boolean isGpsEnabled = aManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Log.i("GPS Status:",isGpsEnabled?"Enabled":"Disabled");
    aManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, aListener);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

Comment: also, the service is running perfectly... just not getting location updates

Comment: update: i tried requesting updates from the network provider and it worked totally fine... might it be a problem because i call an intent service from another instance of intent service? although the intent service works fine

Comment: Just making sure - is GPS turned on? do you get location updates from GPS on another app (e.g. Google Maps)? If not, that might not be an issue with your code but a device setting (or location since GPS won't work inside buildings...)

Comment: thanks for trying but the problem isn't any of what you suggested.

iv'e read some comments in other sections that say that the gps updates should be requested from the main thread. I tried to make a handler - didn't work. tried to make a looper from both services - didn't work... any other suggestions ?

Comment: kk I solved it. 
for anyone who have this problem also.
GPS updates should be requested from the ui thread.
which means you need to create a handler in one of the initiate methods of the context (like onCreate or the constructor).
then, anytime you want to call gps updates just use handler.post(Runnable)..
I created a GPSRequest private class for the service so it will look much more aesthetic.

hope it helped :)

Comment: @RoniLeshes please demonstrate your solution as an answer